# Should I use IActionResult with Produces or ActionResult<> for View()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have method that always produces View(). I would like to mark return type for api explorer(swagger). What is right way to do so in asp.net?

```
public class ProductController {

     [Produces(typeof(MyType))]
     public IActionResult MethodA() { ... }

     public ActionResult<MyType> MethodB() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can, take a look on my solution :**

I explained some very important things to you in the comments, do not forget to read it.

**Controller:**

```
// Declare the ProductService Interface
// ProductService contains all of methods you need to get products information
public class ProductController : Controller
{

    private readonly ProductService _productService;

    // Actions
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var res = new SearchResult<Product>(); // *Product* is a Class in Model that contains all the variables that you need (product properties)
        return View(res);
    }

    public ActionResult GetProducts(DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var result = _productService.GetProducts(request); // GetProducts is a method in ProductService
        return Json(result); // you should build your Json swagger
    }
}
```

**Model:**

*Product.cs :*

```
public string productId { get; set; }
public string productName { get; set; }
public string productPrice { get; set; }
public bool productAvailability { get; set; }
```

*ProductService.cs :*

```
public partial class ProductService : IProductService // IProductService is an interface of IProductService, i will defined it after  ProductService
{
    // To get list of products :
    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        // Initialize new List of products
        List<Product> products= new List<Product>();

        // Your Entity hier
        EntityContext ctx = Enter_youre_Entity_Hier();

        IQueryable<ProductView> query = ctx.ProductViewSet; // At the bottom of the solution you'll find what it is ProductViewSet and how you create one

        return products;
    }

    // Search result
    public SearchResult<Product> GetProducts()
    {

    SearchResult<Product> res;
    EntityContext ctx = Enter_youre_Entity_Hier();
    IQueryable<ProductView> query = 
    DataSourceRequest.BuildLinqQueryFromRequest(Ctx.ProductViewSet);

    query = query.Select(p => p);

    var productSort = query.ToList();

    res = new SearchResult<Product>(
    productSort.ConvertAll<Product>(p => MapProductViewToProduct(p))); // MapProductViewToProduct to mapping the data between Database table "ProductView" to tour local variables in "Product" model

    return res;
    }
    // Mapping data between ProductView and Product
    public Product MapProductViewToProduct(ProductView productView )
    {
    Product product = new Product ();
    product.productId = productView.productId;
    product.productName = productView.productName;
    product.productPrice = productView.productPrice;
    product.productAvailability = productView.productAvailability;

    return product;

    }

}
```

*IProductService.cs :*

You have to defined an interface of ProductService.

```
public interface IProductService
{
    SearchResult<Product> GetProducts();
}
```

**What is ProductView?**

First view in SQL is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement. A view contains rows and columns, just like a real table. The fields in a view are fields from one or more real tables in the database.

**CREATE ProductView :**

```
CREATE VIEW ProductView AS
SELECT productId,
       productName,
       productPrice,
       productAvailability
FROM table_name
```

Then you have to update your Entity Framework to use ProductView.